# shm_open() fails with EINVAL when creating shared memory in subdirectory of /dev/shm

Tags: linux, shared-memory, glibc

I have a GNU/Linux application with uses a number of shared memory objects.  It could, potentially, be run a number of times on the same system.  To keep things tidy, I first create a directory in `/dev/shm` for each of the set of shared memory objects.

The problem is that on newer GNU/Linux distributions, I no longer seem to be able create these in a sub-directory of `/dev/shm`.

The following is a minimal C program with illustrates what I'm talking about:

```
/*****************************************************************************
* shm_minimal.c
*
* Test shm_open()
*
* Expect to create shared memory file in:
*  /dev/shm/
*  └── my_dir
*      └── shm_name
*
* NOTE: Only visible on filesystem during execution.  I try to be nice, and
*       clean up after myself.
*
* Compile with:
*   $ gcc -lrt shm_minimal.c -o shm_minimal
*
******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  int shm_fd = -1;

  char* shm_dir = "/dev/shm/my_dir";
  char* shm_file = "/my_dir/shm_name";      /* does NOT work */
  //char* shm_file = "/my_dir_shm_name";    /* works */

  // Create directory in /dev/shm
  mkdir(shm_dir, 0777);

  // make shared memory segment
  shm_fd = shm_open(shm_file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);

  if (-1 == shm_fd) {

    switch (errno) {
    case EINVAL:
      /* Confirmed on:
       *  kernel v3.14, GNU libc v2.19  (ArchLinux)
       *  kernel v3.13, GNU libc v2.19  (Ubuntu 14.04 Beta 2)
       */
      perror("FAIL - EINVAL");
      return 1;

    default:
      printf("Some other problem not being tested\n");
      return 2;
    }

  } else {
    /* Confirmed on:
     *  kernel v3.8, GNU libc v2.17    (Mint 15)
     *  kernel v3.2, GNU libc v2.15    (Xubuntu 12.04 LTS)
     *  kernel v3.1, GNU libc v2.13    (Debian 6.0)
     *  kernel v2.6.32, GNU libc v2.12 (RHEL 6.4)
     */
    printf("Success !!!\n");
  }

  // clean up
  close(shm_fd);
  shm_unlink(shm_file);
  rmdir(shm_dir);
  return 0;
}


/* vi: set ts=2 sw=2 ai expandtab:
 */
```

When I run this program on a fairly new distribution, the call to `shm_open()` returns `-1`, and `errno` is set to `EINVAL`.  However, when I run on something a little older, it creates the shared memory object in `/dev/shm/my_dir` as expected.

For the larger application, the solution is simple. I can use a common prefix instead of a directory.

If you could help enlighten me to this apparent change in behavior it would be very helpful.  I suspect someone else out there might be trying to do something similar.

Comment: POSIX says slash characters, other than the first character, in the argument to `shm_open` is "implementation-defined" (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html). Practically speaking, I would try (a) running under `strace` to see what is actually happening; and (b) using `my_dir/my_name` without the leading slash just to see what happens. (Although since you are in implementation-defined territory anyway, you might just want to create your own tmpfs and use it directly.)

Comment: @Nemo Thanks, that confirms what I just found reading the glibc source and bug trackers is not a POSIX violation.  I guess the new "implementation definition" is no sub directories.

Comment: Funny how it happens.  Just when I'm about to give up, I find the answer.

Comment: @Nemo Use of `strace` is a good suggestions.  Thankfully, this large app, is one I'm writing, so I can do better by just attaching the debugger.  About the leading `'/'`, now that I've read the glibc code, I can say it will not make any difference.  The first thing they do is remove all leading `'/'` characters.  The implementation is in file `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/shm_open.c`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out the issue stems from how GNU libc validates the shared memory name.  Specifically, the shared memory object MUST now be at the root of the `shmfs` mount point.

This was changed in glibc [git commit b20de2c3d9](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=b20de2c3d9d751eb259c321426188eefc64fcbe9) as the result of bug [BZ #16274](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16274).

Specifically, the change is the line:

```
if (name[0] == '\0' || namelen > NAME_MAX || strchr (name, '/') != NULL)
```

Which now disallows `'/'` from anywhere in the filename (not counting leading `'/'`)

Comment: Nice investigation (+1). Leave it to glibc to interpret "implementation-defined" in the least useful way... That means creating your own tmpfs if you really want the subdirectory structure.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a third party tool that was broken by this shm_open change, a brilliant coworker found a workaround : preload a library that overrides the shm_open call and swaps slashes for underscores. It does the same for shm_unlink as well, so the application can properly free shared memory when needed.

deslash_shm.cc :

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

// function used in place of the standard shm_open() function
extern "C" int shm_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode)
{
    // keep a function pointer to the real shm_open() function
    static int (*real_open)(const char *, int, mode_t) = NULL;
    // the first time in, ask the dynamic linker to find the real shm_open() function
    if (!real_open) real_open = (int (*)(const char *, int, mode_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"shm_open");

    // take the name we were given and replace all slashes with underscores instead
    std::string n = name;
    std::replace(n.begin(), n.end(), '/', '_');

    // call the real open function with the patched path name
    return real_open(n.c_str(), oflag, mode);
}

// function used in place of the standard shm_unlink() function
extern "C" int shm_unlink(const char *name)
{
    // keep a function pointer to the real shm_unlink() function
    static int (*real_unlink)(const char *) = NULL;
    // the first time in, ask the dynamic linker to find the real shm_unlink() function
    if (!real_unlink) real_unlink = (int (*)(const char *)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "shm_unlink");

    // take the name we were given and replace all slashes with underscores instead
    std::string n = name;
    std::replace(n.begin(), n.end(), '/', '_');

    // call the real unlink function with the patched path name
    return real_unlink(n.c_str());
}
```

To compile this file:

```
c++ -fPIC -shared -o deslash_shm.so deslash_shm.cc -ldl
```

And preload it before starting a process that tries to use non-standard slash characters in shm_open:

in bash:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/deslash_shm.so
```

in tcsh:

```
setenv LD_PRELOAD /path/to/deslash_shm.so
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a handy little bit of code to keep in the toolbox.